# Proof by Induction: $∀n ≥ 5, 2^n + 2n < n!$

Tags: induction

I'm having trouble understanding how to solve this question.

Proof by induction:  $∀n ≥ 5, 2^n + 2n < n!$

I don't understand how they got those steps that I highlighted in the picture attached below.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: induction_proof]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

You are assuming $2^k + 2k < k!$ and tring to prove $2^{k+1} + 2(k+1) < (k+1)!$. Because you are assuming $2^k + 2k < k!$ then 
$$2^k + 2k < k! \Rightarrow 2(2^k + 2k) < 2(k!) \Rightarrow 2(2^k + 2k) +2 < 2(k!) + 2$$

and this is the first highlighted step.

For the second one, because $k\geq 5$ (so $k>2$):

$$2(k!)+2 < 2(k!) + k! < 3(k!) < (k+1)(k!)$$

Comment: Thanks for this. Like mentioned before I think I'm lacking some basics on factorials. Can you expand further as to:

Why does 2k!+2  become 2k!+k!, given that k>5?

And why does 3k! become (k+1)(k!)?

Comment: @ThunderBase because $2 < k!$ and $3 < k+1$

Comment: @dcolazin Hi, this is the only way I can reach you. Could you have look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233487/states-of-the-world-game-theory-and-beliefs). I have formulated my problem there.

Answer (score 1):

So first, we need to understand what does one actually do, in induction we first assume that the hypothesis is true for some iteration $k$ and then show that it also holds for $k+1$. After we have checked for some particular value and followed the above step, induction says that the statement is true for any iteration.

We have:
$\forall\ n\ge 5$, W.T.S. $2^n+2n < n!$.
First, see that for $n= 5, 2^5 + 2\cdot 5 = 32+10 = 42 < 5! = 120$. So the statement is true for some value, namely $5$.
Next, we assume it to be true for $n = k$, and try to show for $n =k+1$.

$2^{k+1}+ 2(k+1) = 2\cdot 2^k + 2k +2  < 2(2^k+2k)+2 < 2k! + 2$ (because we assumed that statement is true for $k$) $< 2k! + k!$ (since $k\ge 5$) <3k! < (k+1)! 
Hence we prove the statement for $n =k+1$ and hence it is true for all $n$ by induction.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I'm lacking some basics on factorials. Can you expand further as to:

Why does 2k!+2  become 2k!+k!, given that k>5?

And why does 3k! become (k+1)?

Comment: As commented below, when $k \ge 5, 2 < k!\ \text{and}\ 3 < k+1$.