# States of the world/Game theory and Beliefs

Tags: probability, matrices, matrix-equations, real-numbers, game-theory

This post consists on **3** parts: the *question itself, hint and a table*.
The question will make sense to you only after you have read the tables and the hint attached. The problem is about beliefs of a player in the states of world, which should be naturally read off from the table at the bottom
of this post. However I have problem to do so as explained in my question.

My **question** is:
In the notation
$\pi_i (w_m ; w_k)$
$w_m$ and $w_k$ has together **6** components, say
$w_6=(t'1,a,t'2)$ and $w_8=(t'1,b,t'2)$ while the cell
$\pi_i$
in the table is determined by
**three** components only, say by
$w_6$
**alone, why** I.e. how this problem can be solved?

**Hint:**
There are 8 states:

w1=(t1,a,t2)
w2=(t1,a,t'2)
w3=(t1,b,t2)
w4=(t1,b,t'2)
w5=(t'1,a,t2)
w6=(t'1,a,t'2)
w7=(t'1,b,t2)
w8=(t'1,b,t'2)

The 8x8 block diagonal matrix representing player 1's beliefs (i.e. where row k is the belief of the type of player 1 in wk about (w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6,w7,w8) has 2 blocks (one for t1 and one for t'1), each block is 4x4 in size.  This matrix  (with semicolons representing block margin) is
$$
1,0,0,0; 0,0,0,0\\
1,0,0,0; 0,0,0,0 \\
1,0,0,0; 0,0,0,0\\
1,0,0,0; 0,0,0,0 \\
0,0,0,0; 0,.3,0,.7\\
0,0,0,0; 0,.3,0,.7 \\
0,0,0,0; 0,.3,0,.7\\
0,0,0,0; 0,.3,0,.7\\
$$

the probability  $\pi_i (w_m ; w_k)$ that player i assigns at state $w_k$ to the state $w_m$ is the number in the position $(k,m)$ of the above matrix of player $i$.

**Table:**
[image]

Comment: Is the $\pi_i$ of your previous question the same object as the $T_i$ in this one? They really don't look the same... Also: a way to contact me was through your previous question (and still, my answer wasn't accepted)

Comment: @dcolazin Sorry, I have now accepted your answer. I don't know I have recieved this hint from the second **author** of that snippet from the Handbook of Game Theory wEA. They say "Think of states of the world as a product S x T1 x T2  where states of nature in S describe objective reality and types in Ti represent the state of mind of player i, and where a state of mind is a probability measure on nature and the other player's types.   So each block in the block diagonal matrix has the same type of player i in all its rows, so all rows are the same, but within the block different states diffe"

Comment: different states differ by nature and/or the other player's type. Hence the asymmetry that you mention.

Comment: As noted in another comment, the final probability depends not only on (state of the world, state of mind 1), but on (world state, mind 1 state, mind 2 beliefs): the probability $\pi_1$ is defined over "$S2×\mathcal{B}(S1)$". There is a hierarchy of probabilities/beliefs: there is an "initial" probability where each player believes things independently from each other (the $\pi_i$ of the previous question), then there is a "successive" probability, stacked over the first, where the beliefs of a player are influenced by the initial beliefs of the other. And so on...

Comment: @dcolazin That makes sense to me.Yet, what is exactly ${\cal B}(S1)$ by the pure definition?

Comment: The Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by $S_1$

Comment: So if $S_1$ is finite then it is $2^{S_1}$ ?